# How to find the PHP version that is used by the latest `phpdoc/phpdoc` docker image?

Tags: docker, php

How do I get php version used by docker image [phpdoc/phpdoc](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpdoc/phpdoc)?

Answer (score 1):

The Dockerfile provided in the Q&A indicates that the image uses the latest `php:7` as a base image. One could inspect the version as follows:

```
docker run -it php:7 php -v
```

**Result**

```
PHP 7.3.11 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2019 02:24:51) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.11, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

---

**How to use an older version of php in conjunction with this container?**

It is possible to use a specific version by checking the [tags of php on dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/php?tab=tags). According to this list, `7.2.25` is currently the latest `7.2`. If one changes the from of the Dockerfile to `FROM php:7.2.25` and build the image again, then `7.2.25` instead `7.3.11` will be used inside the container.

Comment: Therefore the image phpdoc/phpdoc use PHP 7.3.11?
I could force you to use another version (e.g. 7.2)?
Or there's some old version of the image phpdoc/phpdoc that uses PHP 7.2?

Comment: But how can I download the Dockerfile related to the phpdoc/phpdoc image?